# get subscriber email on "Confirmation thankyou page" mailchimp

Tags: php, mailchimp, confirmation-email

I am working on mailchimp.
What I want to do is
Get the email entered at signup page at confirmation thankyou page, Which is displayed when user click on the link in email.
I have searched on internet but couldn't find any solution.The flow is like
User submitted form
User clicked on confirmation email.
Now he is redirected to my custom thankyou page.
**How can I get his email address on this page?**

Comment: What researches have you done? This is a quite common problem. Are you familiar with Http-GET parameters?

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Mailchimp doesnot allow to use dynamic links.
Which means I can't use this link
mydomaincom/page?email="email-value"

Comment: could you solve the problem? Would you post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way available to get the email on Custom Thankyou page. The only way to do it is to buy the plan offered by mailchimp. You can't do it with free account.